# Testing mandatory PropTypes passed to Redux HOC's

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, integration-testing, jestjs

I would like to write a test which ensures that a react component passes a prop which has `propType.isRequired` to a child component.

I would like this test to fail if the prop is not provided and pass if it is. I'm using `jest-prop-type-error` to throw errors in my tests.

Given the following two components:

**Parent.js**

```
const Parent = ({ renderReduxChild , childTitle }) => 
    { return renderReduxChild ? <ReduxChild title={childTitle} /> : <NonReduxChild />}
```

**ReduxChild.js**

```
const ReduxChild = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>

ReduxChild.propTypes = { title: PropTypes.string.isRequired }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToProps)(ReduxChild)
```

I would like ensure my `Parent` component passes the `childTitle` prop without needing to write an explicit test which says:

**Parent.test.js**

```
it('should send the required "title" prop to ReduxChild', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Parent renderReduxChild={true} childTitle={'expectedTitle'} />)
  expect(wrapper.props().title).toBeDefined()
})
```

Please note the following:

- If child was not a `connect`ed component, I could `not` pass `childTitle` to `Parent` and the test would fail. Since it is a connected component, if I don't pass `childTitle` the test passes (even though it's required in `ReduxChild`)
- I'm aware that this is quite close to testing the functionality of `PropTypes`, but it's subtly different in that I want to check that `Parent` is using `Child` correctly, not that `ReduxChild` throws a PropTypes error when the prop isn't passed. I want the test to fail at build time when a dev removes the required prop, not at runtime when I exercise the code.

**EDIT:**

To further illustrate the issue, if I have a second child component `NonReduxChild` and give it a `propType` which `isRequired` and have a test for `Parent` which renders the `NonReduxChild` without providing the prop I get an error thrown at build / test time. Wheres with the `ReduxChild` I do not.

**NonReduxChild.js**

```
const NonReduxChild = ({ text }) = <div>{text}</div>
NonReduxChild.propTypes = { text: PropTypes.string.isRequired }
```

**Test output**

```
FAIL  test/components/Parent.test.js (8.782s)

● <Parent /> › when rendering the component › if renderReduxChild is false it should render <NonReduxChild />

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `title` is marked as required in `NonReduxChild`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in NonReduxChild

  28 |   render() {
  29 |     const { renderReduxChild, childTitle } = this.state
> 30 |     return renderReduxChild ? <ReduxChild title={childTitle } /> : <NonReduxChild />
     |                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
  31 |   }
  32 | }
  33 |
```

As you can see from the test output, when I don't provide a required prop to `NonReduxChild` I get a test failure which nicely captures the usage of `NonReduxChild` from other components which might not provide required `PropTypes` I don't get this same failure from `ReduxChild` I have to write a specific test (which I don't want to do across a codebase with hundreds of components).

Comment: It's unclear why *ensure my Parent component passes the childTitle prop without needing to write an explicit test which says* is a requirement. This is a correct way to unit-test a component.

Comment: Well, this is because I don't want to test every single prop on every single `Parent` component which uses a `Child` component throughout a large app. As I mentioned in the notes, if `Child` was not a `connect()`ed component, and my app code didn't pass the `isRequired` prop then any `Parent` test would fail without me needing to write an explicit test.

Comment: Since the question is labeled with `unit-testing`, there's a problem with testing methodology then. *test every single prop on every single Parent component which uses a Child component throughout a large app* - this is how unit tests should be written. What you're describing is integration test, i.e. testing Parent through Child behaviour. Integration tests are often unneeded with good unit test coverage. And they are never a substitute for unit test coverage because they are too broad and imprecise.

Comment: You're definitely right that this is probably more an integration test. I will update tags. In terms of unit testing, the `Child` component does have tests for each required prop so that side of things is covered. 
A required propType for `Child` which isn't provided will blow up in the browser at runtime, rather than at build time which is what I'm after, if you'd like I can update the question to demonstrate how a non redux connected component behaves with the same setup if that makes things clearer?

Comment: *I can update the question to demonstrate how a non redux connected component behaves with the same setup if that makes things clearer?* Yes, this would be fine. I'll try to give an answer then.

Comment: @estus - I've updated to show how a `NonReduxChild` behaves

Comment: I see. I checked the whole thing and I'm not yet sure why a warning can be suppressed with connected component, but I agree with the answer. `prop-types` provides a recommendation (a warning, not an error), while `jest-prop-type-error` is dirty hack around it. So it is very bad material for integration testing because the behaviour you expect in tests doesn't exist in the first place. I still see no good reasons for integration tests here, they just cause more harm than good here. To not assert props, you likely need to mock `Child` with a dummy that throws on wrong props everywhere it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are running into is that PropTypes just logs warnings, which don't actually cause tests to fail.

If the prop is critically important to the operation of the component and you are set on not writing tests to assert that props are present, you could always have the component throw an error if that prop isn't present. That will cause the tests to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm using `jest-prop-type-error` to throw errors in tests, this also doesn't address the parent > child issue, nor the redux vs non redux child differences

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define **title** as prop and u could call it, instead of `"childTitle"`. 
Try this.. it may work

```
it('should send the required "title" prop to ReduxChild', () => {
`var wrapper = shallow(<Parent renderReduxChild={true} title={"expectedTitle"} />);`
  expect(wrapper.props().title).toBeDefined()
  `console.log("",childTitle);`
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but I'm not sure that your answer addresses the issue